# How to change data of reference passed Array in Closure

Tags: php, arrays, reference, closures

I have an Eventbus that takes a filter name as its first parameter and a Closure as second parameter. Like this:

```
$this->EventBus->subscribe('FilterTestEvent', function(){/*Do Something*/});
```

It's called like this:

```
$filteredValue = $this->EventBus->filter('FilterTestEvent', $anyValue);
```

What I want now is to pass an array as reference to the Closure that then is changed in any way (here: add elements) and then return something as the filtered value:

```
$item_to_change = array('e1' => 'v1', 'e2' => 'v2');

$this->EventBus->subscribe('FilterTestEvent', function(&$item){
    $item['new'] = 'LoremIpsum';

    return true;
});

$filtered = $this->EventBus->filter('FilterTestEvent', $item_to_change);
```

Now I would a `print_r($item_to_change)` expect to look like the following:

```
Array
(
    [e1] => v1
    [e2] => v2
    [new] => LoremIpsum
)
```

But instead it looks like the original array:

```
Array
(
    [e1] => v1
    [e2] => v2
)
```

The eventbus internally stores all closures and calls them if needed through `call_user_func_array()` with the closure as first argument and the value as the only argument array element.

How can I achieve what it's meant to do?

Source Code to the Eventbus: http://goo.gl/LAAO7B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found the answer. The filter function needs to be changed so that it accepts arrays as value, in which I can save the reference. For details see difference Revision 1 and Revision 2 of the Eventbus source code, here: [goo.gl/GBocgl](http://goo.gl/GBocgl)

Answer (score 0):

Probably this line:

```
$filtered = $this->EventBus->filter('FilterTestEvent', $item_to_change);
```

is supposed to `return` a new filtered array, not modify the original one.

So check it:

```
print_r($filtered);
```

Passing by reference is possible by modifying a function (adding `&`):

```
function filter(&$array){  //Note & mark
  $array['new_index'] = "Something new" ;
}

$array = array("a"=> "a");
filter($array); //The function now receives the array by reference, not by value.
var_dump($array); //The array should be modified.
```

**Edit:**

---

Make your callback return the filtered array:

```
$this->EventBus->subscribe('FilterTestEvent', function(&$item){
    $item['new'] = 'LoremIpsum';

    return $item ;
});
```

Passing by reference should not work here, because in the source code that `$value` variable is swapped with another value and returned after.

Comment: Actually the $filtered's value should now be set to true since this is what the filter returns.

Yeah, you're right. But the closure does that already.

Comment: What docs do you mean? The Eventbus source code? -- A link is included above.

Comment: You should find what function `FilterTestEvent` does and returns. But `filter` function for sure does not accept array by reference.

Comment: Oh wait, let me see some more.

Comment: Need more source code, preferably some class related to `EventBus`. We need to see what exactly function is responsible for filtering. I see only class `Event`.

Comment: Alright, I think I got how it works: this is the most relevant line `$value = &call_user_func_array($event, array(&$value, $context, $this));`

Comment: Well, if it only works like this, the reference is obsolete, since we are not changing the actual value of this variable, but instead return a copy of it. (Although it should as I understand the references)
Therefore `..., function($item){ ...` is enough if we assign it back to the variable.

Comment: I explicitly wanted the ability to change the parameter without having to return it.

Comment: Well as I wrote, function `filter` does not accept your array by reference, but just by value. So it is not gonna work. The scheme is the following: `create array` -> `call filter(passed by value)` -> `call your callback(passed by reference)` -> `return the result of callback`.